# How can i add notification in layout page ASP.NET Core MVC?

Tags: html, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to make the notifications part in layout. I draw it as a list. But my list only appears when the dashboard is active. I tried creating a separate controller and model for the layout. But I couldn't. I am using ASP.NET Core MVC.

DashboardController

```
[PageAuthorize, HttpGet, Route("~/")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new Yonetim.Common.DashboardPageModel();

    IDbConnection con = SqlConnections.NewFor<MyRow>();

    model.BildirimListe = getBildirimListe(con);

    return View(MVC.Views.Common.Dashboard.DashboardIndex, model);
}

private List<dynamic> getBildirimListe(IDbConnection Connection)
{
        var BireyselBildirimList = new List<dynamic>();
        var GenelBildirimList = new List<dynamic>();
        var BildirimList = new List<dynamic>();

        string sql = string.Format("select * from YonetimBildirimBayi YBB inner join YonetimBildirim YB ON" +
            " YB.Id = YBB.BildirimId where YBB.BayiId = {0}", Authorization.UserId);

        //genelbildirimler
        string sql2 = string.Format("select * from YonetimBildirim where " +
            "BildirimTuru=3");

        BireyselBildirimList = Connection.Query(sql).ToList();

        GenelBildirimList = Connection.Query(sql2).ToList();

        BildirimList = BireyselBildirimList.Concat(GenelBildirimList).ToList();
  
        return BildirimList;
}
```

`Layout.cshtml`:

```
@model Yonetim.Common.DashboardPageModel

    <ul class="menu">
         @if (Model != null)
          {
             @if (Model.BildirimListe != null)
              {
                  @foreach (var item in Model.BildirimListe)
                  {
                     <li>
                     <a onclick="addRiskRule('@item.BildirimAdi','@item.BildirimIcerik');" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalHomeEvents">
                     <i class="fa fa-users text-aqua"></i> @item.BildirimAdi
                     <br/> @item.BildirimIcerik
                     <br/>
                     <span class="footer" style="font-size:9px">
                     @item.BildirimTarihi.Date.ToString("dd MMM yyyy")
                     </span>
               </a>
          </li>
       }
   }
}
</ul>
```

`DashboardPageModel.cs`:

```
public class DashboardPageModel
{
    public List<dynamic> BildirimListe { get; set; }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZ0Qr.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjoJx.png)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for getting back to you late. It was giving an error like "value of null" because the list returned empty. I solved this problem without using session. I called a service with "get" on my layoutindex.cshtml page. I put the result returned from this service to the list in the modal. Then I formatted the html with the returned response. I sent this

```html
<ul>
  <li>
  </li>
</ul>
```

HTML that I formatted to the div id I added to the page. This was the best solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

> But my list only appears when the dashboard is active.

You can try to bind your list , notifications part in layout using session . You can add below code:

1.DashboardController:

```
const string SessionKey_BildirimListe = "sessionkey";
[PageAuthorize, HttpGet, Route("~/")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    IDbConnection con = SqlConnections.NewFor<MyRow>();
    var BildirimListe = getBildirimListe(con);
    string BildirimListeJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(BildirimListe);
    HttpContext.Session.SetString(SessionKey_BildirimListe, BildirimListeJson);
    return View();
}
```

2.In Program.cs(asp.net core 6.0+) or startup  add  following session related services in ConfigureServices() function :

```
builder.Services.AddSession();
...
app.UseSession(); // for sessions
```

3.Fetch the data on the  _Layout.cshtml :

```
       @using Newtonsoft.Json;
       @{
            string json = string.Empty;
            json = Context.Session.GetString("sessionkey");
            List<dynamic> BildirimListe = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<dynamic>>(json);
        }
<ul class="menu">
        
                  @foreach (var item in BildirimListe)
                  {
                     <li>
                     <a onclick="addRiskRule('@item.BildirimAdi','@item.BildirimIcerik');" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalHomeEvents">
                     <i class="fa fa-users text-aqua"></i> @item.BildirimAdi
                     <br/> @item.BildirimIcerik
                     <br/>
                     <span class="footer" style="font-size:9px">
                     @item.BildirimTarihi.Date.ToString("dd MMM yyyy")
                     </span>
                     </a>
                     </li>
                   }
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I added as you said, but the session empties after a while and gives an error. I need to go to the dashboard page to get it back to the session. It seems to be working but I keep getting an error. there must be another way.please help me !

Comment: @ŞebnemSeymen  "but the session empties after a while and gives an error. "  We set  `Route("~/")` before Index(), so we will go to Index() first, then set session value  first like: HttpContext.Session.SetString.  "It seems to be working but I keep getting an error. " What's error? Could you share it ?